# subdomain with Windows 7 + Apache + Cakephp

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, subdomain

I am setting up a local dev environment on windows that accept subdomains.
so far on my host file i have

```
127.0.0.1       test.press.lc      #subdomain site, since we cant have dynamic subdomain
127.0.0.1       press.lc           #the main site
```

and in apache conf, i have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName press.lc
    DocumentRoot D:/htdocs/web/press/
    ServerAlias *.press.lc
</VirtualHost>
```

i can access press.lc without any problem, but when i try to access test.press.lc. i get redirected to external site(in this case it's earthlink search, since it thought i made a typo in my url). Is my setup wrong? plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the name resolution first using a tool like `nslookup` or `ping`. Try flushing your DNS cache first (`ipconfig /flushdns` at the command-line).

If that works, you have to search for the problem in your browser (own DNS cache etc.).

The redirection to an external ("domain not found") page indicates that your Apache setup shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: thanks. it straightened itself out after a while. so i guess its some kinda cache problem.